# Multitable join is taking hours, is there a better way?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a few tables recording trades by myself and trades that happen in general, separated out into tradelog and timesales respectively. Both tradelog and timesales each have a second table holding extra data about the trades. I have a column TimeSalesID in my tradelog so I can link up public trades which I participated in. Below is the query I'm running to try and get ALL of my trades and time and sales in one result. The right join is taking FOREVER though, is there a better way?

```
    SELECT SUM(tsJoin.TradeEdge)
    FROM
    (SELECT * from tradelog tl JOIN slippage_processed sp ON tl.ID = sp.TradeLogID WHERE tl.TradeTIme > '2019-01-21') AS tlJoin
    RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT * from timesales ts JOIN slippage_processed_timesales spt ON ts.ID = spt.TimeSalesID WHERE ts.TradeTime > '2019-01-21') AS tsJoin
    ON tlJoin.TIMESalesID = tsJoin.ID
```

Comment: Please share the structure of your tables (including indexes). One thing I noticed is that you use `select *` twice but you only need two columns (join column and aggregation column). This definitely increases IO usage without good reason.

Comment: seems you're branching two aggregates from the common root TimeSalesID. You should probably be able to this off without subquerys, just two branches of outer joins. (Subqueries are performance killers)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Not using subqueries would help.  MySQL tends to materialize subqueries, which means that indexes are lost -- greatly impeding query plans.

I would start with:

```
select sum(?.TradeEdge)  -- whatever table column it comes from
from timesales ts join 
     slippage_processed_timesales spt 
     on ts.ID = spt.TimeSalesID left join
     tradelog tl
     on ?.TIMESalesID = ?.ID left join
     slippage_processed sp 
     on tl.ID = sp.TradeLogID and tl.TradeTIme > '2019-01-21'
where ts.TradeTime > '2019-01-21';
```

The `?` are because I don't know the base tables where the columns are coming from.  Depending on the tables, the query might need to be adjusted a bit.

Also, I don't think the outer joins are necessary for what you want to do.

Comment: (Newer version of MySQL will go to the effort of concocting an index for a derived table.  In `EXPLAIN`, look for `<auto-key>`.)

Answer (score 1):

You should simplify your sql to simple JOINs. Based on your query above, I think this might get you a result a little faster

```
SELECT SUM(TradeEdge)
    FROM tradelog tl 
    INNER JOIN slippage_processed sp ON tl.ID = sp.TradeLogID
    INNER JOIN  timesales ts  ON ts.ID = sp.TimeSalesID
WHERE tl.TradeTIme > '2019-01-21'
```

If this does not work, please post your table structure for all tables involved